# How does Journey Builder match mobile numbers at send time?

Tags: journeybuilder, mobileconnect

I currently have a journey using an API event source. When I open the journey builder settings, it gives the user the option to choose where the email address comes from (i.e. the event source, event source then channel address order, or channel address order).

How does this work if there is a mobile send included in the journey? I have a field containing mobile number...how do I map this to the journey?